# Unterschied: Vorfall, Zwischenfall und Vorkommnis?

Tags: synonym

Wo liegt der Unterschied zwischen folgenden Wörtern: Vorfall, Zwischenfall und Vorkommnis?

Comment: Was weißt Du schon dazu bzw. hast Du in Wörterbüchern gefunden? Was ist Dir noch unklar?

Comment: Das Problem ist, dass alle 3 Wörter die selbe Bedeutung  haben wenn ich sie ins Polnisch (meine Muttersprache) übersetzten will, d.h. es gibt ein Wort im polnischen für alle 3 Wörter...

Comment: Man muss keine Übersetzungs-Wörterbücher benützen. Man kann auch einsprachige Bedeutungs-Wörterbücher nehmen. Wie wäre es mit dem Duden?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Die drei Wörter sind sehr nah verwandt und sind in vielen Situationen austauschbar, aber es gibt auch kleine Unterschiede:

- Ein **Vorfall** ist gewissermaßen der "kleine Bruder" des **Unfalls** und bezeichnet ein unplanmäßiges Ereignis, das zwar noch kein definitiver Unfall ist, aber für gewöhnlich immer noch als negativ angesehen werden kann (zumindest in dem Sinne, dass es den vorgesehenen Ablauf unterbricht)

> Im Kraftwerk gab es einen Vorfall, deshalb muss die Umgebung evakuiert werden.

- Ein **Zwischenfall** ist eine Unterart des Vorfalls - es wird dabei betont, dass das Problem zwischenzeitlich gelöst (oder zumindest in beruhigender Weise  abgemildert) worden ist.

> Im Kraftwerk gab es einen Zwischenfall, aber jetzt läuft der Betrieb wieder planmäßig.

- Ein **Vorkommnis** ist ein neutraleres Wort für eine auffällige Begebenheit, und kann am ehesten auch für positive Überraschungen (auch ironisch) verwendet werden. Im Gegensatz zum Vorfall und Zwischenfall muss es sich nicht unbedingt um ein plötzlich aufgetretenes Ereignis handeln.

> Im Kraftwerk gab es ein Vorkommnis, als die jährliche Inspektion durchgeführt wurde, und zwar war ein Backup-Sicherheitssystem schon seit ein paar Monaten defekt.
>
> Im Kraftwerk gab es ein besonderes Vorkommnis: Der Chef war zum ersten mal gut gelaunt.

Answer (score 3):

Diese drei Wörter sind einander auch im Deutschen sehr ähnlich.

Der **Vorfall** kommt vom Verb *vorfallen*, das *geschehen* oder *passieren* bedeutet.

> Es ist etwas vorgefallen. — Was für ein Vorfall denn?

Zu **Zwischenfall** gibt es kein entsprechendes Verb. Der Zwischenfall ist ein Ereignis, der eine andere Sache vorübergehend unterbricht.

> Es gab einen kurzen Zwischenfall. Und dann ging es weiter.

Das **Vorkommnis** ist eine Wortbildung analog zum Verb *vorkommen*. Dieses Wort wird eher selten verwendet, meistens als Euphemismus.

> Da gab es ein Vorkommnis. — Was genau denn?